# How to force subclass to call an abstract implemented method

Tags: java, inheritance, implementation, abstract

Basically, what I want to do is **force** the subclass to call an abstract superclass method (implemented in the subclass), so I don't have to explicitly write it each time I create a new subclass.

I wrote it in the superclass' constructor once, because I want it to force it for every implementation.

```
public abstract class SupahClass {
    public SupahClass() {
        doStuff(); // It IS executed when the subclass constructor is called
        init(); // NOT executed, even though it's implemented
    }

    private void doStuff() { ... }        

    protected abstract void init();
}

public class SomeSubClass extends SupahClass {

    // The problem lies HERE: this is executed AFTER init() ... so it gets NULL again
    private TextBox myTextBox = null;

    public SomeSubClass() {
        super(); // invokes the super constructor, so init() should be called
        // I could call init(); here EACH time i create a new subclass... but no :)
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.myTextBox = new TextBox(); // Executed BEFORE its declared as null above
    }
}
```

Of course, the superclass can't really call it since its an abstract (so undefined) method, but its an ABSTRACT class so it cannot be instanciated, it must delegate the task to its subclasses, so why cant they call the abstract but now implemented method?

**EDIT** 
See the subclass property `myTextBox` and the `init()` implementation

Which approach do you think I should do? Remove the `= null` in the property declaration (duhhh)

or remove the `init()` in the superclass and explicitly calling it in the subclass constructor (this is what I wanted to avoid, since I will have to write it 100% of the time..)

Comment: That will work. This is clearly not your actual code - your actual code must differ from this in some important way. Why not post your actual code and let us have a look?

Comment: Indeed! see my comment on Jon Skeet's answer and my updated question  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by changing your declaration to:

```
private TextBox myTextBox;
```

The assignment to null serves no useful purpose. If there was no superclass, it would do nothing, because fields are initialised to null anyway. Since there is a superclass, it acts as a gunshot to the foot. So, get rid of it.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I did for the moment to fix this, but you made me realise it's not useful at all and is indeed a bad practice.

I can't even think of a case where it'd be useful... I guess I'll remove these assignments everywhere I used them. But other than that, what do you think of my current implementation (of calling such methods in the constructors)?

Comment: It is, as everyone will tell you, a dangerous practice. It opens the door to some quite tricky bugs (methods running against partially-constructed objects, unsafe object publication, etc). However, it doesn't unavoidably cause those bugs - it's still up to programmers to introduce them. If there was no advantage to calling a subclass method from a constructor, i'd advise you to never do it. But often, it's a simple and clear way of getting the behaviour you want, with no straightforward alternative. So, there's a judgement call about whether the value of the call outweighs the risk of bugs.

Comment: That's a judgement call that depends on context - on how complex the invariants around the class are, how skilled the programmers who work on the codebase are, whether the class will be widely extended, or is confined to a small part of the system, etc. It's a specific question, to which i can't give you a general answer. Jon Skeet can, of course :).

Answer (score 8):

I can't reproduce this. `init()` *will* be called, assuming no exceptions are thrown first. Short but complete example:

```
abstract class Superclass {
   public Superclass() {
       init();
   }

   protected abstract void init();
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
   public Subclass() {
       super();
   }

   @Override
   public void init() {
       System.out.println("Subclass.init called");
   }
}

public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Subclass();
    }
}
```

That prints "Subclass.init called" as expected. I suspect something else is wrong in code that you haven't shown us.

Note that calling virtual methods in a constructor is a risky business - the subclass won't have been initialized yet - all the variables will have their default values, for example. It's generally a pattern to be avoided.

Comment: was about to suggest this but no shame in being beaten to it by Jon Skeet

Comment: You're absolutely right.. I tought Init was never called because at some point one of the subclass properties was null when it was supposed to be initialized.

You're twice as right when you said it's a risky business because the subclass won't have been initialized : that exactly was my problem. See my updated Question at the end for more information, and I'd really like your feedback on which approach you think I should use .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes **can** call abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a debugger to understand what the code is doing?

The order of construction is 
1. constructor of base class
2. initialize all members of derived class
3. constructor of derived class.

In your case step 1 initializes the member (in init of the derived class - called via polymorphic call) but step 2 sets it to null.